# Understanding Taylor's Theorem for multivariate functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider Taylor's theorem up to 3rd term.
\begin{align*}
    f(\vec{x}) &= f(\vec{a}) + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(\vec{a})}{\partial x_i} (\vec{x}_i - \vec{a}_i) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i_1, i_2 = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f(\vec{a})}{\partial x_{i_1} \partial x_{i_2}} (\vec{x}_{i_1} - \vec{a}_{i_1}) (\vec{x}_{i_2} - \vec{a}_{i_2}) + \sum_{|\beta|=  3} R_3(\vec{x})(\vec{x} - \vec{a})^3
\end{align*}
where the last term is written using multi-index notation. Now in my understanding
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{|\beta|=  3} R_3(\vec{x})(\vec{x} - \vec{a})^3 = \frac{1}{3!} \sum_{i_1, i_2, i_3 = 1}^n \frac{\partial^3 f(\vec{y})}{\partial x_{i_1} \partial x_{i_2} \partial x_{i_3}}  (\vec{x}_{i_1} - \vec{a}_{i_1}) (\vec{x}_{i_2} - \vec{a}_{i_2}) (\vec{x}_{i_3} - \vec{a}_{i_3}) \tag1
\end{align*}
where $\vec{y} = \vec{a} + t(\vec{x} - \vec{a})$ for some $t \in [0, 1]$.

But from wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions), it seems that
\begin{align}
    \sum_{|\beta|=  3} R_3(\vec{x})(\vec{x} - \vec{a})^3 &=  \sum_{i_1, i_2, i_3=1}^n  \left [ \frac{3}{3!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{2} \frac{\partial^3 f(\vec{a} + t(\vec{x} - \vec{a}))}{\partial x_{i_1} \partial x_{i_2} \partial x_{i_3}} dt\right ] (\vec{x}_{i_1} - \vec{a}_{i_1}) (\vec{x}_{i_2} - \vec{a}_{i_2}) (\vec{x}_{i_3} - \vec{a}_{i_3}) \tag2
\end{align}

How do I reconcile $(1)$ and $(2)$? Am I misreading the formula on wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

As we know:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}(1-t)^2dt=\frac{1}{3}$$
So it's enough to use [mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=g(c)\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$
where $\exists c \in (a,b)$